# Angular Clarity: What is expected behavior of setting clrPosition to bottom-right

Tags: angular, clarity, vmware-clarity

Any idea if using `[clrPosition]=bottom-right` resulted into the style

```
left: 0px; 
right: auto;
```

as shown given below in **HTML** for corresponding **Clarity-Angular** code?

**Clarity-Angular**

```
<clr-dropdown-menu [clrPosition]="'bottom-right'">
.
.
.
</clr-dropdown-menu>
```

**HTML:**

```
<clr-dropdown-menu _ngcontent-c1="" 
      ng-reflect-position="bottom-right" 
      class="dropdown-menu" 
      style="position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: auto; left: 0px; right: auto; 
      visibility: hidden;>
    .
    .
    .
</clr-dropdown-menu>
```

I was expecting a style of:

```
left: auto; 
right: 0px;
```

That's because I want the dropdown to organically grow on left hand side (auto) and be fixed towards the right (0px) of containing block. (Btw, I did try `[clrPosition]=bottom-left` but it caused no change to `left` and `right`.)

Actually, if I look closely, some Clarity CSS is actually trying to do the right thing for the same `clr-dropdown-menu` by manually setting `left=auto` and `right=0` as shown in picture below but its getting overridden and therefore eventually because of this issue, I get a horizontal scroll bar in my whole app. That's the main issue I am fixing here.

[image]

Can you check if this a bug or expected behavior? Is there a better way to set the left and right to expected values?

I cannot even override left and right to correct values because of the higher specificity acquired by Clarity CSS as it used 'style' attribute for setting the styles. Is there any other clean way where I don't have to change Clarity's CSS code?

Comment: Clarity uses the `transform: translateX() and translateY()` CSS rules for positioning of the dropdown. Can you show a plunkr with the issue you're having? https://plnkr.co/uNwwZe

Comment: Not sure if I can reproduce it via plunkr. Transform property appears when a click on dropdown happens. My problem is there even if no one ever clicks the dropdown. You may see from my html that visibility is still hidden. Still, clr-dropdown-menu is causing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

@baltoro: Did you try using the `*clrIfOpen` directive on the `clr-dropdown-menu`? Please refer to this Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/PDyoV6iLRgrtgGhzzRjM?p=preview

```
<clr-dropdown>
  <button clrDropdownTrigger class="btn">
    Dropdown Toggle
    <clr-icon shape="caret down"></clr-icon>
  </button>

    <clr-dropdown-menu *clrIfOpen clrPosition="bottom-right">
      <label class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</label>
      <a href="javascript://" clrDropdownItem>Action 1</a>
      <a href="javascript://" clrDropdownItem>Action 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a href="javascript://" clrDropdownItem>Link 1</a>
      <a href="javascript://" clrDropdownItem>Link 2</a>
    </clr-dropdown-menu>
</clr-dropdown>
```

Using the `*clrIfOpen` plnkr should avoid the horizontal scrollbars because the menu is removed from the DOM when not open.